# How to make a line have a checkerboard pattern?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I am trying to make a YouTube intro with powerpoint. The main basis for it however is a circle that alternates between gray and blue in a checkerboard pattern. I tried to use the format shape tool then line, but there is no line pattern. Is there a way to make the circle have a checkerboard pattern in the line?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a checkerboard pattern within the border of the circle. If that's the case, you should start with a hollow circle or donut shape.

You can set it to use a pattern fill, which will provide you with many more options than are available with the dashed border line approach. Once you find the checkerboard pattern you are looking for, grab the yellow handle to adjust the area or thickness of the shape. 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on your shape and choose the option "Format Shape" you get a side panel showing the properties. Expanded the one called "Line" and choose your "Dash type".

[image: Dash type property]

In my second example I have removed the fill and changed the line type to dashed to make it clearer what the options do.

[image]

Comment: I cannot see that checkerboard requested by the OP.